# The FTP I'm using for school is not working with ANY given .aspx web pages

Tags: asp.net

I tried uploading a simple .HTML webpage as well as a .PHP webpage. They both worked perfectly fine. But when using Visual Studio asp.net and making websites with visual basic, the WebForm.aspx pages created when I publish my projects don't work. I get the error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Assignment_1_MattAndrzejczuk.WebForm1'.

Source Error: 
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="Assignment_1_MattAndrzejczuk.WebForm1" %>
```

This is for a school assignment, I know for a fact that the web server works and I've tested .HTML and .PHP pages on this web server, they work perfectly fine. But I don't know why I can't do the same with .aspx pages.

Comment: Are you deploying all the files or just copying over the .aspx pages?

Comment: Visual Studio has a "publish" menu which will transfer all of the files needed by your app (not just the aspx pages) via FTP.

Comment: Which kind of web server they have? Apache? IIS?

Comment: The server I'm using is: http://csc-srv1.lasalle.edu/ and I use FTP as the publish method in visual studio.

Comment: With ASP.NET you need to configure the application root in IIS. You can't just publish it because the pages need to know where to find the code-behind.

Comment: Can you post the source code of `WebForm1.aspx.vb` - it seems it's a build error more than anything. The fact that your code behind and type name are different is a clue (not to say that they must always be the same).

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the root folder as an application in IIS? It appears that ASP.NET doesn't know where to go to get to the bin folder.

Comment: I do not believe so, what does IIS mean?

Comment: It's the platform of the web server. You'll probably need to speak with your network admin.

Answer (score -3):

Schools generally offer Linux environment and their web servers only allow PHP (I think it is because both Linux and PHP are open source). There are plenty of free ASP.NET hostings online.

Regards.

Comment: Yes it is, I know that for a fact. When working with ASP.NET locally I would get a similar looking error page for my never-ending loops or other minor bugs.